# Value of type 'VisionFace' has no member 'contour' swift error

Tags: swift

when I am using this code for face detection its showing Value of type 'VisionFace' has no member 'contour' how can I solve this issue???

```
private func addContours(forFace face: VisionFace, transform: CGAffineTransform)
{

    // Face

    if let faceContour = face.contour(ofType: .face)
    {
      for point in faceContour.points
        {
            drawPoint(point, in: .blue, transform: transform)
        }
    }

    // Eyebrows
    if let topLeftEyebrowContour = face.contour(ofType: .leftEyebrowTop)
    {
      for point in topLeftEyebrowContour.points
      {
           drawPoint(point, in: .orange, transform: transform)
      }
    }
    if let bottomLeftEyebrowContour = face.contour(ofType: .leftEyebrowBottom)
    {
      for point in bottomLeftEyebrowContour.points
      {
           drawPoint(point, in: .orange, transform: transform)
      }
    }
    if let topRightEyebrowContour = face.contour(ofType: .rightEyebrowTop)
    {
      for point in topRightEyebrowContour.points
      {
            drawPoint(point, in: .orange, transform: transform)
      }
    }
    if let bottomRightEyebrowContour = face.contour(ofType: .rightEyebrowBottom) {
      for point in bottomRightEyebrowContour.points {
        drawPoint(point, in: .orange, transform: transform)
      }
    }
}
```

Please see my code image and give the proper solution how can I fix that Issue??  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XsqJ.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're including the Firebase MLKit libraries in your podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'
```

and then make sure you're doing

`import FirebaseMLVision`

at the top of your .swift file

I'm basing my solution on [Firebase's sample code on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/mlvision/MLVisionExample/UIUtilities.swift)

Comment: Thanks #Michael Dautermann  for comment but I import FirebaseMLVision still error is not fixing....

Comment: Do you have `import Firebase` at the top of your swift file?  Does that make a difference?

Comment: #Michael Dautermann Yes I also import Firebase you can see given list of pods I imported                       import UIKit
import FirebaseMLVision
import FirebaseMLModelInterpreter
import Firebase